# Zeppelin: Pig script issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run Pig scripts on Zeppelin:

```
%sh
sudo -u niyya hadoop fs -put /Users/MrsGrandChamps/Downloads/Building_Permits.csv /Pig_Data

%pig
permits = load '/Pig_Data/Building_Permits.csv';
permit = foreach permits generate $0 as PermitNumber;
dump permit;
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.6.0   0.17.0  root    2018-10-22 17:35:23 2018-10-22 17:35:31 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1540230095274_0004  permit,permits  MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp912998135/tmp982591067,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/Pig_Data/Building_Permits.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp912998135/tmp982591067"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1540230095274_0004


 INFO [2018-10-22 17:35:31,956] ({pool-2-thread-7} MapReduceLauncher.java[launchPig]:527) - Failed!
ERROR [2018-10-22 17:35:31,975] ({pool-2-thread-7} PigInterpreter.java[interpret]:110) - Fail to run pig script.
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias permit
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1020)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:782)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:383)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerScript(PigServer.java:781)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerScript(PigServer.java:858)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerScript(PigServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.pig.PigInterpreter.interpret(PigInterpreter.java:99)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:633)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1013)
    ... 18 more
 INFO [2018-10-22 17:35:31,979] ({pool-2-thread-7} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:115) - Job 20181022-121300_2022450011 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.pig.PigInterpreter1485066214
```

I've tried a few different things but I am not sure where the issue lies exactly. I'm also getting a similar error when trying to run the tutorial for Pig in Zeppelin as well. I know I'm missing something I just need some new eyes.

Comment: Which engine do you use ? mapreduce or tez ? And please check the yarn logs if you run this pig script in yarn cluster. Could you try use `hdfs:///Pig_Data/Building_Permits.csv` ?